# Deep Beans initialization with thread-specific data in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, initialization, javabeans

Spring's dependency injection mechanism looks convenient because I don't have to create classes manually from root class and pass them to deeper classes. But what if I have 3 separate threads which do the same job and have some thread-specific data which should be spread through the class hierarchy?

Consider the following App:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Properties props = new Properties(); 
        props.load(App.class.getResourceAsStream("/application.properties"));

        String[] domains = props.getProperty("domains").split(",");

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class);
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory = context.getBeanFactory();

        for(String domain : domains) {
            DomainListener listener = factory.getBean(DomainListener.class);
            listener.setDomain(domain);
            listener.start();
        }
    }

}

@Service
@Scope("prototype")
public class DomainListener extends Thread {

    @Autowired
    EventPublisher publisher;

    String domain;

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("starting '" + domain +  "' domain thread...");

        publisher.setDomain(domain); // <-- is this the best way to initialize bean?

        // some processing

        publisher.publish("Some event");
    }

}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class EventPublisher {

    String domain;

    public void setDomain(String domain) {
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    public void publish(String msg) {
        System.out.println("publishing '" + msg + "' to '" + domain + "' domain");
    }

}
```

`application.properties` file content

```
domains = domain1.example.com,domain2.example.com,domain3.example.com
```

`DomainListener` and `EventPublisher` classes can't be initialized with `domain` value automatically by Spring, thus I have to call `setDomain` method and pass the domain value manually, first during `DomainListener` thread construction, then in `DomainListener.run()` to initialize `EventPublisher` with domain value. Would I need to pass the value even deeper, for example from `EventPublisher` to some other class, say `MessageBuilder` (let's assume it requires domain value), then I would have to call `MessageBuilder.setDomain()` instance method from `EventPublisher` constructor (as it is the same domain thread).

Can this be improved somehow?

Comment: Just define them as `@Bean` methods... Or create a factory.

Comment: Well, suppose I have a `@Configuration` class with `@Bean` annotated methods. Inside that method, I can initialize the bean with some data. But how do I pass, for example, `domain` value to that method? How do I know which thread a bean being constructed will be returned to?

Comment: Why not pass that stuff around, that is what method arguments are for or put it in a thread local. But for some reason it looks like you are trying to use the wrong approach for this.

Comment: Yes, for me it also looks like a wrong approach (that one which I have described). That is why I've asked the question. As I explained there can be multiple threads, depending on domains specified in the config file. Each domain is served by the same service on the backend. Actually, the service is doing the same job for each domain, but each domain has own context. I'm building another service which must cooperate with the service.

Comment: BTW, ThreadLocal is a good suggestion. Thank you!